# Python don't accept importing module name with '-'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a module with name as 'downloadflat-modular.py', python fails to import this module

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import downloadflat-modular
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import downloadflat-modular
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from downloadflat-modular import *
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from downloadflat-modular import *
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Is this a restriction ?

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: _Is this a restriction ?_ - Yes. Python cannot tell that `downloadflat-modular` is all one identifier. Just change it to use `_`.

Answer (score 4):

Package names are identifiers and thus they can not contain hyphens.

Identifiers in python must **start** with a lowercase/uppercase letter or an underscore, and can contain digits in the rest of the name.

---

According to PEP8 the suggested style is as follows:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a restriction, you could say.

`-` is the subtraction operator, so Python interprets `downloadflat-modular` as "`downloadflat` minus `modular`", which is not allowed after an `import` statement.

Basically, you cannot (and shouldn't) name anything in Python with a `-` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, python `import` can only accept valid identifiers.

Choices are:

1. You may change the file to `downloadflat_modular.py` and then `import downloadflat_modular`
2. or you can use the `importlib.import_module("downloadflat-modular")`.

Comment: Though the second option seems to me pretty dangerous... I think it would be better to simply avoid naming modules with hyphens. Is it something accepted by PEP8?

Comment: @Rightleg of course not, it's strongly not recommended, but a viable option